# What's a RegEx to match any numeric OR question mark?

Tags: c#, regex, string, formatting

I'm using this Regular Expression `"\d+"` to match any numeric (0-9)
in my code, but how can I alter it to also include question marks?

For example, I want 04/??/1992 to return 04??1992, and I want -123?6 to return 123?6, and I want just 123 to return 123. Basically, I want to match any number (0-9) and question marks only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If you're downvoting my question then at least let me know why? So I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[]` operator to specify the character class, which expands what is allowed to match.

Your solution would be `[\d?]+`

Comment: No need to escape the question mark inside the character class. That will also match a plus sign since it's within the class (the brackets). The plus belongs outside

Answer (score 0):

This should cover your needs: `string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d?]", "");`.